# How do I get the path from MEDIA_ROOT to save it as a string in my Model?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

So, I've successfully uploaded and saved my uploaded files in the "Media" directory in my project. Now what I'm trying to do is get the path of the saved file and save it as a string in my CharField made in my model. Executing

```
data1.append('doc1', $('#file1').val())
```

gets the path where the file is originally saved like this:
`C:\fakepath\<filename>`. However, what I need is the full path of the media directory where I've saved the file via the form, which would be: `C:\Users\bilal\PycharmProjects\<proj name>\media\<filename>`.

So how would I go about getting this done? I'm sharing the complete project for clarity as well.

Thank you.

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="data">
            <label for="docn">
                <input type="text" id="docn" placeholder="Please enter document name">
            </label>

            <label for="docc">
                <input type="file" id="doc" name="docu">
            </label>

            <button type="button" onclick="enterdata()">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function enterdata() {

        var data1 = new FormData()
        data1.append('dcn', $('#docn').val())
        data1.append('dc', $('#doc').val())
        data1.append('docf', $('#doc')[0].files[0])

        var token = '{{ csrf_token }}';
        alert('csrf generated');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user',
            data: data1,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': token},
            success: function () {
                alert("Added");
            }
        })

    }
</script>
</body>
```

**views.py**

```
def insert(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def testing_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dcn1 = request.POST['dcn']


        upload_file = request.FILES['docf']
        path = upload_file.url(upload_file)
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(upload_file.name, upload_file)




        FileDB.objects.create(
            docname=dcn1,
            doc=path,
        )

        return HttpResponse('')
```

**settings.py config**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: try to get the path after saving the file

Comment: Why would you want the _absolute path on the server_ of a user upload inside your Javascript context? It is a security failure to trust the user not to mess with this path.